# python xml.etree.ElementTree parse

Tags: python, xml, soap

The SOAP envelop looks like following. I need to parse the following in python. I tried following without any luck.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = mytree.getroot()
```

I tried Namespaces and XPath
Can someone help as I am new to python? Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <env:Body>
            <dp:response xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management">
            <dp:timestamp>2008-03-18T17:48:22+01:00</dp:timestamp>
            <dp:config>
                <User xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" name="xyz" 
                    <mAdminState read-only="true">enabled</mAdminState>
                    <userSummary>admin</UserSummary>
               </User>
               <User xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" name="abc" 
                    <mAdminState read-only="true">enabled</mAdminState>
                    <userSummary>admin</UserSummary>
               </User>
            </dp:config>
        </dp:response>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML is not well-formatted, you're missing a `>` at the end of each `user` tag. Also `userSummary` is not case matching with `UserSummary`. After these fixes, you can go ahead and start parsing the file as follows.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

namespaces = {
    'soap': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
    'dp': 'http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management'
}
users = root.findall('./soap:Body/dp:response/dp:config/User/userSummary', namespaces=namespaces)
for user in users:
    print(user.text)
```